# Larger lowercase small-caps in Times?

Tags: fonts, small-caps, times

The lowercase small-caps provided by the times package are too small for my taste. The lowercase characters appear smaller relative to the uppercase ones than they do in, say, computer modern or garamond. Is there a package that provides larger lowercase small-caps for a times-like font (e.g., a lowercase-to-uppercase differential comparable to that in computer modern)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a comparison of the available Times-like fonts in TeX distributions:

[image]

I believe that Times small caps are a later addition, and they depend on how the font designers thought best. My preference goes to the smaller variant, to be honest.

Note that `mathptmx` uses rather large small capitals because it has no real small caps font and the small capitals are reduced size capital letters, so the developer of the virtual font chose not to make them too small, since this would show much clearly the fake.